# Suddenly I can't load some newly upgraded modules in Python

Tags: python, anaconda

I suddenly can't load newly upgraded modules modules, e.g scikit-learn, zope, but I can find other packages. Even though the **path** links from the import points to the correct anaconda folder, which contains all the code. Any ideas what might be wrong and how to fix it?

```
Python 2.7.13 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Dec 20 2016, 23:09:15) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2
>>> import sklearn
>>> from os import listdir
>>> print(dir(sklearn))
['_ASSUME_FINITE', '__SKLEARN_SETUP__', '__all__', '__builtins__', '__check_build', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__version__', '_contextmanager', 'base', 'clone', 'config_context', 'exceptions', 'externals', 'get_config', 'logger', 'logging', 'os', 're', 'set_config', 'setup_module', 'sys', 'utils', 'warnings']
>>> print(listdir(sklearn.__path__[0]))
['exceptions.py', 'cross_validation.pyc', 'lda.py', 'naive_bayes.pyc', 'isotonic.py', '_build_utils', 'neighbors', 'cluster', 'naive_bayes.py', '__init__.pyc', 'multiclass.py', 'dummy.pyc', 'grid_search.pyc', 'tests', '__init__.py', 'calibration.py', '_isotonic.so', 'neural_network', 'datasets', 'preprocessing', '__check_build', 'random_projection.py', 'multiclass.pyc', 'model_selection', 'calibration.pyc', 'pipeline.pyc', 'qda.py', 'learning_curve.py', 'ensemble', 'tree', 'isotonic.pyc', 'kernel_ridge.py', 'gaussian_process', 'decomposition', 'base.pyc', 'dummy.py', 'utils', 'pipeline.py', 'cross_decomposition', 'covariance', 'qda.pyc', 'multioutput.pyc', 'lda.pyc', 'feature_selection', 'linear_model', 'metrics', 'kernel_ridge.pyc', 'setup.py', 'semi_supervised', 'exceptions.pyc', 'multioutput.py', 'cross_validation.py', 'discriminant_analysis.py', 'kernel_approximation.pyc', 'base.py', 'random_projection.pyc', 'setup.pyc', 'kernel_approximation.py', 'grid_search.py', 'discriminant_analysis.pyc', 'mixture', 'manifold', 'externals', 'svm', 'feature_extraction', 'learning_curve.pyc']
>>> import zope
>>> print(dir(zope))
['__doc__', '__name__', '__path__']
>>> print(listdir(zope.__path__[0]))
['interface']
>>> zope.interface
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'interface'
>>> sklearn.lda
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'lda'
```

Comment: You sure you've got the latest version of sklearn?

Comment: you better import using, for example: ```from sklearn.ensemble import BaggingClassifier```

Comment: I am sure I have used the latest version and I have also tried the other import method.

Comment: The snippet doesn't show the actual *errors* that you're now seeing - what traceback do you get when the import fails?

Comment: Thanks now it is updated. So python is not able to see the code or the folders in the folder. Returning an 'AttributeError'

Comment: `DeprecationWarning: lda.LDA has been moved to discriminant_analysis.LinearDiscriminantAnalysis in 0.17 and will be removed in 0.19
  "in 0.17 and will be removed in 0.19", DeprecationWarning)` Your version is too new perhaps. Also for zope, can you try `import zope.interface` instead of `import zope`?

Comment: Uvar. Same problem with the other import methods. It is not the related to the error as stated as the dir(sklearn) outputs neither the files or folders in the package. So the package do not see the folders and files in the repo. The lda python file is in the correct folder as the listdir(sklearn.__path__[0]) shows and the same for the interface folder. But thanks for investigating it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

sadly but true... your error is real..but the below warning message as well. Use `sklearn.discriminant_analysis.LinearDiscriminantAnalysis` from now on. How to deal with the other possible persisting error is also updated into my answer. Enjoy!

> ```
> import warnings
> from .discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis as _LDA
>
> warnings.warn("lda.LDA has been moved to "
>           "discriminant_analysis.LinearDiscriminantAnalysis "
>           "in 0.17 and will be removed in 0.19", DeprecationWarning)
>
> class LDA(_LDA):
>     """
>     Alias for
>     :class:`sklearn.discriminant_analysis.LinearDiscriminantAnalysis`.
>
>     .. deprecated:: 0.17
>     This class will be removed in 0.19.
>     Use
>     :class:`sklearn.discriminant_analysis.LinearDiscriminantAnalysis`
>     instead.
>     """
>     pass
> ```

No errors when running below code:

```
import sklearn

from sklearn import discriminant_analysis
from os import listdir

print(dir(sklearn))

print(listdir(sklearn.__path__[0]))

print discriminant_analysis.LinearDiscriminantAnalysis()
```

snippet output:

> [Assume_FINITE', ...]
>
> ['base.py', ...]
>
> LinearDiscriminantAnalysis(n_components=None, priors=None, shrinkage=None,
>                 solver='svd', store_covariance=False, tol=0.0001)

As it seems your code goes wrong somewhere and somehow. Your best option for now is:

1 - delete your scikit-image, sklearn and zope folders from folder ../site-packages;

2 - delete folders + content of **scikit_image-0.13.0-py2.7.egg-info, scikit_learn-0.19.1-py2.7.egg-info and zope installer folder**
 into the trashbin;

3 - `delete` folders from trashbin (prevents linkage to folders within the trashbin);

4 -run pip install scikit-image/sklearn/zope with option  `--no-cache-dir`;

5 **Voila...** you get a running skimage, sklearn and zope again.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

It's not that you can't load them. As you can see, you did `import` them successfully with no error messages appearing.

However, it seems that the modules *zope* and *sklearn* do not have the attributes that you are trying to use with them.

try:

> `from zope.interface import Interface`

and the same for *sklearn*:

> `from sklearn import lda`

I hope this helps. If not, try reinstalling the packages.

**Note that**: you cannot simply just use `pip install package` because you are required to install other dependencies as well. Here are the pages with the installation instructions for:

1. zope:
   https://zope.readthedocs.io/en/latest/INSTALL-buildout.html
2. sklearn:
   http://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html

Comment: from my experience pip handles dependencies by downloading them as well if not installed.

Comment: @ZF007 I agree. But I read in zope that they advise not to rely on pip and rely on their installation instructions in their page. Sklearn has no problems with pip.

Comment: ..I am curious on which page you that it was mentioned.. I can't find it (maybe I had too much free time during the weekend). Hence, the dual way `zc.buildout` or `virtualenv`/pip combo is clearly described.

Answer (score 1):

The Attribute error that you are presenting is the expected behaviour of Python3. Did you upgrade from Python 2 to Python 3 Because there are many differences between both version families... read more about this here: 
https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html

To load the sklearn.lda module you have to explicitly import the part of the module that you need.

> from sklearn import lda

or

> import sklearn.lda

I hope this answers your question!

Comment: As stated in the code this problem I am having is on a Python 2 anaconda instance and as stated in the comments I have tried the other import methods. And the problem is seemingly unrelated. Now you scratch your head I do to :)

Answer (score 0):

A useful way to get around this problem in the future is to use virtual environments. It will allow you to have different versions of packages running on the same machine. This means that you can upgrade your packages for your new code, but you can still run your old code on the same machine.

If you are using Anaconda then https://conda.io/docs/using/envs.html is the description.

If you are ever using a cpython distribution [virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html) is an amazing tool.

While it doesn't solve your problem directly, spending an hour getting comfortable with this will stop dependancy issues for you in the future saving you a lot of time in the future.